# In C++, how can I properly store a BYTE type in a variable?

Tags: c++, winapi

Apologies in advance if this is obvious or has been answered elsewhere. I've been searching for a few hours but my inexperience with C++ makes it likely that I lack the appropriate vocabulary to form appropriate search terms.

The problem I'm having arises in the context of using [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-module-list) of code that list's all modules used by a particular running process.

I'm struggling to find a way to store the output produced by the following line of code in a variable:

```
    _tprintf( TEXT("\n     base address   = 0x%08X"), (DWORD) me32.modBaseAddr );
```

From the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-moduleentry32), it looks like 'me32.modBaseAddr' is a pointer to a BYTE type variable. The above code very beautifully prints out the correct hex address held in me32.modBaseAddr into the console.

What I want to do is store me32.modBaseAddr into a variable that can then be passed to std::ofstream (I want to write it to a file).

I'm sure I'm failing to understand something fundamental so even if someone could even point me in the right direction for what I need to be learning about that would be really useful.

Thanks!!

Comment: modBaseSize is a `DWORD`.

Comment: Do you really mean `modBaseAddr`?

Comment: Ah my bad. That's right.

Comment: As for writing the `modBaseSize` member to a C++ stream, just if it's a text-stream just write it normally using the `<<` operator.

Comment: Sorry guys. I've edited now.

Comment: %d is wrong. It's an address, a pointer. Use %p, and don't cast the address to DWORD. Some of these ancient MS examples don't use good practice. What do you want to write to the file. The address and the memory at that address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood it right you want to save that line of formatted text?

C style is the best for it, do not use reinterpret cast, you only make compiler work harder, and prevent it from making optimizations to your code. Just simply use that code:

```
char var[256];
sprintf(var, "\n     base address   = 0x%08X", me32.modBaseAddr);
```

Comment: Makes me feel stupid that this was so simple but thank you!

Comment: This fails for a 64 bit process because the pointer is 16 hex digits

Comment: Luckily I happen to be looking at a 32 bit process, but out of curiosity, would there be something similarly as simple that would work for a 64 bit process?

Comment: @David Heffernan, that is true, thats why for printing of pointers you should always use '%p', but if you have stored 64bit address in the 32bit variable before that has no sense. In this case macros could be use.

Comment: If you put a 64 bit address into a 32 bit variable, then nothing can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The `modBaseAddr` member is, basically, a pointer to the first element of an array of `modBaseSize` elements. Each element is a `BYTE`.

So to write all the raw binary data to a stream (opened in binary mode) you could do e.g.

```
my_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(me32.modBaseAddr), me32.modBaseSize);
```

Comment: That address is surely for a module in a different process.

Comment: This really helped with my understanding. Thanks dude.